# Problem with the integer value in an SQL syntax: #1366 error

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I was making a php website with some forms that let you make a form which let's you make an account, but for some reason when I was checking the SQL I was using inside phpmyadmin...

The SQL code it gave me an error that of

> #1366 Incorrect integer value

Here is the SQL code I was checking:

```
INSERT INTO Users VALUES ('','$username','$password','0','empty')
```

The weird thing about this is the fact that the integer ID, which is in auto-increment, as I've learned it should be blank in the syntax like I've done (the ID column is the first one in my table)

Comment: If you write inserts like those are asking for problems  you should explicit  mention the columns   like `INSERT INTO Users (some_name, username, password, some_name, some_name) VALUES('','$username','$password','0','empty')`

Comment: Also you should research about SQL injections as your SQL and PHP code is prone..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are inserting rows into a table, the best practice is to always list the columns:

```
INSERT INTO Users (col1, col2, col3, col4)
    VALUES ('', '$username', '$password', '0', 'empty');
```

I don't know what your column names are, so you have to fill them in.

If you are writing application code, another best practice is to use proper *parameters* rather than munging a query string with values.